# how to order files using a regex in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

For each individual I have a folder that contains 4 different files. Assuming there're 3 individuals, I'd like to create a regular expression that returns the files in the following order:

```
path/to/individual1/a_01.txt
path/to/individual2/a_01.txt
path/to/individual3/a_01.txt
path/to/individual1/a_02.txt
path/to/individual2/a_02.txt
path/to/individual3/a_02.txt
path/to/individual1/a_03.txt
path/to/individual2/a_03.txt
path/to/individual2/a_03.txt
path/to/individual1/a_04.txt
path/to/individual2/a_04.txt
path/to/individual3/a_04.txt
```

With three individuals it isn't a problem to do it manually but when there're hundreds, a more automated way to do this would be convenient.

I suppose I'll have to select `a_01.txt` `a_02.txt` and `a_03.txt` first for each individual:

```
f = dir('path/to/individual1/')
f1 = regexp({f.name},'a_0[1-3].txt','match')
f2 = [f1{:}]
```

and repeat this for the other individuals. But then how can I achieve the desired result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend it to indifidual's too.

`individual[1-3]/a_0[1-3].txt`

**edit** - of course this is just a filter, regex's can't sort.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean doing something like: regexpi({f.name},'individual[1-3]/a_0[1-3].txt','match')? I tried this but it didn't work... {f.name} in this case came from f = dir('path/to/'), and thus shows the folders of individual1, individual2 and individual3.

Comment: @HappyPy - Can't you give it an option to list all sub-dir files. In Windows command line for example it is `C:> dir /s`.

Comment: Actually its `C:> dir /B /s` in Windows. Where /B is bare format (full path and filename).

Comment: If you get it to work, might have to change the regex to account for end of string: `individual[1-3]/a_0[1-3].txt$`

Comment: As I just noticed, in Windows you could use `[s, f] = dos('dir /B /s');` then f1 = regexp({f.name},`'^.*individual[1-3]/a_0[1-3].txt$'`,'match'); Where `regexp` is in multi-line mode. Or, for Linux have to use their equivalent.